# Telerik control RasMaskedTextBox is not showing error message

Tags: c#, telerik

I am using CustomValidator for Telerik RadMaskedTextbox.The problem is that if i don't put any value , it doesn't show errormessage.

```
<telerik:RadMaskedTextBox ID="RadMaskedTextBox3" runat="server"
                                        Width="150"
                                        Mask="(###) ###-####  ext. #####">
                                    </telerik:RadMaskedTextBox>
 <asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator4" runat="server"                                        
                                        ErrorMessage="*"
                                        Display="Dynamic"
                                        CssClass="error1"
                                        Enabled="false"
                                        ToolTip="At least one Phone no: needs to be filled in."
                                        ValidateEmptyText="true"
                                        EnableClientScript="true"
                                        OnServerValidate="CustomValidator_ServerValidate"
                                        SetFocusOnError ="true"                                             
                                        ValidationGroup="CarrierBaseInformation1">
                                    </asp:CustomValidator>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you are another example with a CustomValidator:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator1" runat="server"
    ClientValidationFunction="CheckLength"
    ErrorMessage="Phone\Fax numbers must be 7 or 9 digits"
    ControlToValidate="txtTollFree">*</asp:CustomValidator>
<script>
function CheckLength(source, args)  
{  
    if (args.Value.length == 10 || args.Value.length == 13)  
    {  
        args.IsValid = true;  
    }else{  
        args.IsValid = false;  
    }  
} 
</script>
```

Comment: Perfect! Glad to be able to help!

Comment: Can you please mark the provided answer as valid? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example how to achieve your goal:

In the Web.config set

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="ValidationSettings:UnobtrusiveValidationMode" value="None"/>
```

In the aspx

```
<telerik:RadMaskedTextBox Mask="(###) ###-####  ext. #####" RenderMode="Lightweight" ID="RadMaskedTextBox1" runat="server" EmptyMessage="Enter username"></telerik:RadMaskedTextBox>

<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" Text="*" ControlToValidate="RadMaskedTextBox1"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="PostBack" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Rumen. I am sorry there is slight change in my question, instead of RequiredFieldValidator , I am using CustomValidator.